# EC2 hosts Django with IP address can't be assigned-to error

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, ip

I have a EC2 instance want to run Django app on it. This EC2 instance already have a Apache server on port 80. Now I want to host my Django project on port 9090. The instance has static IP 200.200.200.200.

> ubuntu@ip-10-242-229-213:~/flanders$ python manage.py runserver
>   200.200.200.200:9090 Validating models...
>
> 0 errors found Django version 1.3.1, using settings
>   'flanders.settings' Development server is running at
>   http://200.200.200.200:9090/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C. Error: That
>   IP address can't be assigned-to. ubuntu@ip-10-242-229-213:~/flanders$

It tells me `Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to`, So I change to

> ubuntu@ip-10-242-229-213:~/flanders$ python manage.py runserver
>   127.0.0.1:9090 Validating models...
>
> 0 errors found Django version 1.3.1, using settings
>   'flanders.settings' Development server is running at
>   http://127.0.0.1:9090/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

The application starts without problem but when I try to access it `http://200.200.200.200:9090/flandersapp/tags`, I doesn't work. By the way, I allow port 9090 in my security setting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved myself. I need to use the private IP provided by EC2 instead of public IP

Comment: when I gave private IP address it runs but when I gave public IP:<port no> in the browser it does not work. Can you please tell me how to run public IP:<port no> from the browser?